# obtain the address of a node given a node address in a linked list

Tags: c++

So I have a pretty good understanding of iterating through a linked list, and also obtaining the next node in the list. Now I trying to go in the other direction, but I soon realized its not as easy as it appears. Unlike an array where you can iterate forwards and backwards. I seem to be stumped.

So If I have a list of 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> NULL How would I go about obtaining the address of node 2 given the location of node 3?

I started messing around with this code below which returns all items up to node 3. I just don't see how I can get that previous node? By the way `searchList()` returns the address of a node if you give it the node->data value. Using the list above `searchList(3)` returns the address of the node which has 3 as its data member.

```
struct node {
    int data;
    node* next;
};

void llclass::getPrevious() {
    node *stop = searchList(nodeItem),
         *start = head;

    while (start != stop) {
        cout << start->data << endl;
        start = start->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to get the previous node of a node whose value is given as input to you. This should do that for you:

```
node* llclass::getPrevious(int item)
{
   node* previous = NULL;
   node* current = head;
   while(current)
   {
      if (current->data == item)
      {
          return previous;
      }
      else
      {
          previous = current;
          current = current->next;
      }
   }
   return NULL;
}
```

Comment: thank you this preciously what I am trying to accomplish. One thing why did you return NULL at the end?

Comment: If the item you are looking for is not in the list, then you don't have a valid previous node to return to the caller. To inform the calling code of this scenario I chose to return NULL.

Answer (score 1):

With a singly-linked list like yours, it is not possible to obtain the address of node 2 if you're given only the address of node 3.  You would have to start at the head node and iterate forward until reaching 3, keeping track of the previous node (2 in this case).  Alternately, you could use a doubly-linked list that includes a "node *previous;" member.

Comment: For this problem, using a doubly-linked list will still yield only an O(n) algorithm, not to mention the cost of having n additional pointers!

Comment: True, given the new information, but he said he was given the location of node 3, which I assumed meant the address of node 3.  If that's the case, a doubly-linked list would enable an O(1) "algorithm" (i.e., just dereference the 'previous' pointer).